# Property not being set after model is updated

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

My application is using MVVM and exposes the properties on the model by using getter properties on the view model. The problem I am having is when I set one of my properties on the model, the property on the view model that gets the property from the model is not being updated - the get/set is never called after the property on the model is set. If I breakpoint on the `ColourR` of the view model, neither the get or set is hit after `SelectedColour` is set even though `ColourR` on the model is being set.

The `ColourR` property on the model is set by the view model when `SelectedColour` on the view model updates the property on the model. The text box on my view is binded to the `ColourR` property on the view model, which should get the value of the property on the model, but whenever this value changes it is not updating correctly.

If I bind the textbox directly to the model using `{Binding LineAppearanceLayerDefinition.ColourR}`, it works correctly but I would like to understand why the binding does not work with my property on the view model as I would prefer to bind this way.

Model:

```
public class AppearanceLayerDefinition : BindableBase
{
    private string _colourR;
    public string ColourR
    {
        get { return _colourR; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _colourR, value);
        }
    }

    private Color _selectedColour;
    public Color SelectedColour
    {
        get { return _selectedColour; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedColour, value);
            ColourR = value.R.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class AppearanceLayerDefinitionLineViewModel
{

    public AppearanceLayerDefinitionLineViewModel(ApperanceLayerDefinition appearanceLayerDefinition)
    {
        LineAppearanceLayerDefinition = appearanceLayerDefinition;
    }

    public LineAppearanceLayerDefinition { get; private set; }

    public Color SelectedColour
    {
        get { return LineAppearanceLayerDefinition.SelectedColour; }
        set
        {
            LineAppearanceLayerDefinition.SelectedColour = value;
        }
    }

    private string _colourR;
    public string ColourR
    {
        get { return LineAppearanceLayerDefinition.ColourR; }
        set
        {
            LineAppearanceLayerDefinition.ColourR = value;
            SetProperty(ref _colourR, value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource AppearanceLayersTextBoxGroupStyle}" Text="{Binding ColourR}" />
```

Comment: This code does not compile. `public LineAppearanceLayerDefinition { get; private set; }`

Comment: Also, how would the ViewModel know about the change? You do not register for `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: The view model doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so it can't pass state changes to the form. That and the SETer for ColourR doesn't save the current value to it's own backing variable.

Comment: Tried with `SetProperty` but it still does not work. Edited post to show usage of `SetProperty`. Since I am using `SetProperty` on the model I thought it did not need to be used on the view model also?

Comment: The ViewModel should be declared as public class AppearanceLayerDefinitionLineViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I am using Prism which uses BindableBase for property changes.

Comment: Then it should inherit from that.

Comment: Your ViewModel should also inherit Bindable base. SetProperty is what notifys the the UI to update. Then you can bind UI elements to your ViewModel.